# How long does it take to create a team in Dota 2

Tags: dota-2

I recently tried to create a team in dota 2, uploaded all banners and stuff from omij's guide, but I got nothing after a modal came up daying Creating Team with an OK button which I clicked. I'm not able to create a team with the same name again, so I think it got created, but it does not appear in My Teams. How long does it take to create a team?

Comment: I think it should be instant so either it'd a bug, either the team already exists and the creation just failed

Comment: Maybe steam / dota2 network was down. you should post into the dev forum of dota2 about this: http://dev.dota2.com/forum.php

Comment: I've created two teams, albeit with no images, but both were created instantly, when I found a name that wasn't taken.

Comment: Yeah so I created a team with a slightly different name and it was created instantly too. Now what do I do to this question?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a team is instantaneous.  You should see it in `My Teams` after, with you as the only member.

If you don't, you need to create another team. Any issues you have with duplicates will have to be resolved unless you manage to get Valve to fix it.